# Defining types of Vue 2.x components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue 2.6 in my project

I want to define props of component for specific cases (for dynamic component in child component with passed props)

Here is some sample code

```
// child component

<template>
  <component :is="someProp.passedComponent" />
</template>

import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
 name: 'SomeComponent'
})
export default class SomeComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop() readonly someProp!: { passedComponent: Vue }
}
```

```
// parent component

<template>
  <some-component :some-prop="someDataForProp">
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

import DummyComponent from './components/DummyComponent.vue'

@Component({
 name: 'ParentComponent'
})
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  private someDataForProp = { passedComponent: DummyComponent }
}
</script>
```

```
// DummyComponent.vue

<template>
 <div>{{ title }}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  name: 'DummyComponent'
})
export default class DummyComponent extends Vue {
  private title = 'This is dummy component for example'
} 
</script>
```

But when I define Component type as `Vue`, It makes some error like this

> Type 'typeof DummyComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'Vue': $el, $options, $parent, $root, and 39 more.

I wonder if there is **one** type that can encompass all components defined with @Component.

Comment: What exactly `someData` should look like? Is passedComponent really a property? How is DummyComponent defined?

Comment: @EstusFlask I add a definition of `DummyComponent.vue` for declarative example
`someDataForProp` is a data that pass to child component because child component need a component for rendering dynamic component with component binding

Answer (score 0):

`passedComponent` is expected to be a component itself that is used `<component>`, while `Vue` type refers to Vue component instance, i.e. component ref.

It should be:

```
@Prop() readonly someProp!: { passedComponent: typeof Vue }
```